# How to model F-Holes of a violin

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to figure out how this 3D artist modelled the F-holes in this violin model.
I have traced out the violin, and also the F-Hole Shape, I was curious to see how a Boolean operation would look, in case I can clean it up, merge it with vertices, but its very condensed. I tried to see some 3D violin modelling on YT, but they're all time lapse videos, and this particular section on the violin is not shown. So any suggestions seeing the 3D mesh, how the artists made the F-shape?

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe don't apply the Subdivision Surface, then draw the shape and join with the existing topology? If you have a low-poly, version, please share it

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=jdkq80xs" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/jdkq80xs/)

Comment: Hello, you just have to replicate the topology in the image you provided, it's pretty straightforward. You need to dissolve some of your loop cuts to facilitate your task

Comment: I am making some progress I believe: https://ibb.co/RQL1Vyt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would go the other way around, begin with the hole shapes, then draw the whole shape:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip, working from within towards outwards seems better topology.